# Список в Java

Tags: java

Ребята, подскажите плиз как реализовать метод для обмена значений заданного и следующего за ним элемента в списке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такого метода нет. Вы можете руками проставить значения по индексам через set

**UPD**

Простите, я вас обманул. Используйте [Collections.swap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html).